# Kafka Connect over SSL issue - Can't connect Broker - Brokers found []

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

Does Kafka connect really work to connect broker bootstrap server running in SSL port.
If I change to PLAINTEXT://broker.local:9092 in Connect config it works but container failed to load with SSL://broker.local:19092 .
So wonder if connect really needs non-SSL config ?

I am getting below issue during container launch . No other issue with broker and zookeeper.

```
connect          | Error while getting broker list.
connect          | java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listN         odes
connect          |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
connect          |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2005)
connect          |      at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
connect          |      at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:147)
connect          |      at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:149)
connect          | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
control-center   | [2024-02-29 17:37:20,612] INFO unable to get command store (io.confluent.command.CommandStore)
connect          | Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Trying to query Kafka for metadata again ...
connect          | Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Brokers found [].
connect          | Using log4j config /etc/cp-base-new/log4j.properties
connect exited with code 1
```

Below is my Zookeeper , Broker and Connect config :

```yaml
---
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.3
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks:
       kafka:
          aliases:
            - zookeeper.local
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
      ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
    volumes:
      - zk-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zk-txn-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:7.5.3
    container_name: broker
    networks:
       kafka:
          aliases:
            - broker.local
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "19092:19092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper.local:22181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://broker.local:19092
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.broker.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: broker_keystore_creds
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: broker_sslkey_creds
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.broker.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: broker_truststore_creds
      KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
      KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_INTERNAL_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker.local:19092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper.local:22181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.metrics.truststore.jks
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.metrics.keystore.jks
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: awesomekafka
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: awesomekafka
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: awesomekafka
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: anonymous
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.5.3
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    networks:
      # - localnet
       kafka:
          aliases:
            - connect.local
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker.local:19092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR,com.mongodb.kafka=DEBUG"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/confluent-hub-components
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper.local:22181
```

Answer (score 0):

incase anyone has same issue .. I solved this problem as : looks like the missing config on Connect will be needed to communicate over SSL port :

```
    CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL 
    CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.connect.truststore.jks 
    CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: awesomekafka 
    CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL 
    CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.connect.truststore.jks 
    CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: awesomekafka
```